# Solving a transistor circuit and determine the base current

Tags: transistors

I need to determine the base current of the circuit I have attached below.
Given:

current amplification \$B = 500\$
\$U_{CC} = 12V\$
\$U_{BE} = 0.7V\$
\$R_C = 3.2k \Omega\$
\$R_E = 9k \Omega\$
\$R_1 = 47 \Omega\$
\$R_2 = 19 \Omega\$

[image: transistor circuit]

What we need to get: 
base current \$I_B\$ in $\mu A$ (2 decimals)

My attempt: (feel free to correct me if I use the wrong vocabulary to describe my attempt, thank you!)

At first I introduced a new current \$I_q\$ which flows through \$R_2\$. Having that done I know that \$I_q = \frac {U_{BE}}{R_2}\$. Since \$U_{BE} = 0.7V\$ and \$R_2 = 19 \Omega\$ are given I calculated the value for \$I_q \approx 0.03684210526A\$.
Now I looked at the top left part of the circuit. We know that \$R_1\$ must be \$R_1 = \frac {U_{CC} - U_{BE}}{I_q + I_b}\$. Well solve the equation for \$I_b\$. We then receive \$I_b = \frac {U_{CC} - U_{BE}}{R1} - I_q\$. If we fill the equation with the given values and \$I_q\$ we get: \$I_b = \frac {12V - 0.7V}{47} - 0.03684210526 = 0.2035834267A\$. Now we need to convert \$I_B\$ to \$\mu A\$ which should be \$203583,43 \mu A\$ (rounded).

Comment: I think you forgot to take into account the voltage drop acress $R_E$. The Voltage drop across $R_2$ is $U_{BE}$ + $U_{R_E}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At first I introduced a new current Iq which flows through R2. Having
>   that done I know that Iq=UBE/R2.

This is incorrect; the voltage across R2 is \$U_{BE} + I_E R_E\$

Also, I suspect that the values of R1 and R2 should be in \$k\Omega\$ and the value of \$R_E\$ is suspiciously high.

Regardless, there's a step by step approach to finding \$I_B\$.

Form the Thevenin equivalent circuit looking out of the base:

\$U_{BB} = U_{CC} \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}\$

\$R_{BB} = R_1 || R_2\$

Now, write the KVL equation around the base-emitter loop:

\$U_{BB} = I_B R_{BB} + U_{BE} + I_E R_E\$

Using the relationship:

\$I_E = (\beta + 1) I_B\$

Substitute and solve:

\$I_B = \dfrac{U_{BB} - U_{BE}}{R_{BB} + (\beta + 1)R_E}\$

---

You can ignore this if you like, but you ought to, before turning in or publishing an answer, do a sanity check to make sure that, on the face of it, your answer isn't *hopelessly, impossibly wrong*.

For example, consider the answer you give for the base current and the implication of it.  If the base current *were* 0.2A, as you've calculated, the emitter current, which is 501 times the base current, would be an *enormous* 102A.

It's always good to do a sanity check on your answer.  Even if \$U_{CE}\$ were zero, the emitter current could not be any larger than:

\$I_{E_{max}} = \dfrac{U_{CC}}{R_C + R_E} = 984\mu A\$

This places an *upper bound* on the base current which is:

\$I_{B_{max}}= \dfrac{I_{E_{max}}}{\beta + 1} = 1.96\mu A\$

So, by making a very quick calculation, you have a good sanity check for any answer you may come up with.

Comment: I am sorry @Alfred Centauri that I dissapointed you. For my further approaches I will perform the sanity check before posting here. I never heard of the Thevenin equivalent before but Wikipedia gave me a brief overview which in my opinion is satisfying. Again I would like to thank you that you put effort in my problem. You helped me to understand the approach. Sadly I lack a lot of physical and electronical practice which is mirrored in my poor topics. However the correct $I_B$ must be $0.6108975 \mu A$. Hope I got it right this time :)